# Ephemeral SSL certificates for Electron app

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, electron

I'm currently developing an Electron application in which a WebView Process communicates over HTTPS with a local Node.js Server Process spawned from within the same Electron application.

Because the application has control over the URL loaded on the WebView Process, as well as the HTML content being rendered, I'm not concerned about man in the middle attacks. Also, the WebView Process is the only Client accessing this Server at any given time.

I'm just concerned about passive eavesdropping.

For this reason I need to my Node.js Server Process to serve content over HTTPS.

My options are:

1. Generate a self signed certificate and private key and distribute them with my application: This compromises the private key, so I'm not happy with this.
2. Enforce [Perfect forward secrecy](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#perfect-forward-secrecy) on top of #1, but I'm not sure how to do that.
3. Generate some random ephemeral certificate/key at runtime, just for the session. For this I would need some Node.js built-in API, rather than CLI.

Thanks on advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I think I got this and all pretty much thanks to this [post](https://www.techengineer.one/how-to-generate-x-509v3-self-signed-certificate-in-pem-format-with-node-js/).

The post basically explains how to use [node-forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) to create a self-signed certificate at runtime.

This means:

1. I don't need to bundle a certificate and a private key with my electron application.
2. I can generate a new ephemeral certificate and private key for each new session.
3. The ephemeral private keys (as well as certificates) are never saved to filesystem.

To make this work in an Electron/Node environment, I made two extra things:

1. Use Electron's `certificate-error` event to avoid errors derived from using my self-signed certificates.
2. For performance reasons, I used node.js native `crypto` lib in order to generate the private/public key pairs, which can be later imported into `node-forge` by using `privateKeyFromPem` and `publicKeyFromPem` methods.

On top of that I can also enforce Perfect Forward Secrecy ciphers, but I think does not add real extra security in this particular scenario.

Comment: Oh I am really interested in seeing how you pulled this off but it seems like that article is no longer available.

I am especially curious how you got electron to pass the certificate to the API calls you are making? In my scenario I am trying to call an external device that requires mutual auth. So ideally on load will call my PKI to issue a certificate for the session that would be valid to the external device.

Comment: @AndresFGarcia please take a look, this is how I use it. Hope it helps https://gist.github.com/ncortines/7fa5fc66b50d28e9452f775780e6d918